# Is there an R function for selecting the maximum value in one column associated with an ID in an adjacent column?

Tags: r, dplyr

This is an example of what I'm working with. hh_p_id is an individual and tdtrpnum is identifying each trip they made per day, I want to find the average number of trips taken per day per person. To start, I want to separate (maybe filter?) the highest value per individual. How can do I do that?

[image: screenshot of table because I don't know how to format it in text]

Comment: you could use data.table maybe. Something like `dt[,which.max(tdtrpnum), by=hh_p_id]`

Answer (score 1):

If `my_data` is your data.frame then:

```
my_data <- my_data %>%
  group_by(hh_p_id) %>%
  summarise(avg_per_day = n() / length(unique(date))
```

will give you average number of trips per day for column hh_p_id

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using dplyr if you want to calculate min, max and average number of trips per person ...

```
library(magrittr)
# some sample data
data <- dplyr::tibble(ID=sample(1:10,size=1000,replace=T),
                      DATE=sample(1:20,size=1000,replace=T) %>%
                          as.Date(origin="2020-01-01")) %>%
    dplyr::group_by(ID,DATE) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(CNT=dplyr::n())

# solution to your problem 
data %>%
    dplyr::group_by(ID) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(AVG=sum(CNT)/dplyr::n(),
                  MAX=max(CNT),
                  MIN=min(CNT))
```